# Scrapy doesn't crawl the page

Tags: scrapy

I want to crawl a page `http://www.jcvi.org/charprotdb/index.cgi/l_search?terms.1.field=all&terms.1.search_text=cancer&submit=+++Search+++&sort.key=organism&sort.order=%2B` by scrapy. But seems there is a problem that I didn't get any data when crawling it.

Here is my spider code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy_Data.items import CharProt


class CPSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "CharProt"
    allowed_domains = ["jcvi.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.jcvi.org/charprotdb/index.cgi/l_search?terms.1.field=all&terms.1.search_text=cancer&submit=+++Search+++&sort.key=organism&sort.order=%2B"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//*[@id="middle_content_template"]/table/tbody/tr')

        for site in sites:
            item = CharProt()
            item['protein_name'] = site.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract()
            item['pn_link'] = site.xpath('td[1]/a/@href').extract()
            item['organism'] = site.xpath('td[2]/a/text()').extract()
            item['organism_link'] = site.xpath('td[2]/a/@href').extract()
            item['status'] = site.xpath('td[3]/a/text()').extract()
            item['status_link'] = site.xpath('td[3]/a/@href').extract()
            item['references'] = site.xpath('td[4]/a').extract()
            item['source'] = "CharProt"
            # collection.update({"protein_name": item['protein_name']}, dict(item), upsert=True)
            yield item
```

Here is the log:

```
2016-05-28 17:25:06 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-05-28 17:25:06 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-05-28 17:25:06 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-05-28 17:25:07 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.jcvi.org/charprotdb/index.cgi/l_search?terms.1.field=all&terms.1.search_text=cancer&submit=+++Search+++&sort.key=organism&sort.order=%2B> (referer: None)
<200 http://www.jcvi.org/charprotdb/index.cgi/l_search?terms.1.field=all&terms.1.search_text=cancer&submit=+++Search+++&sort.key=organism&sort.order=%2B>
2016-05-28 17:25:08 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-05-28 17:25:08 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 337,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 26198,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 28, 9, 25, 8, 103577),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 28, 9, 25, 6, 55848)}
```

And when I run other spiders, they all works fine. So can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code? Or there is something wrong with this webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are crawling it but your xpath is wrong

When you inspect an element with your browser the `<tbody>` tag appears but it's not anywhere in the source code therefore, nothing is to be crawled!

```
sites = sel.xpath('//*[@id="middle_content_template"]/table/tr')
```

That should work

edit

As a side note `extract()` returns a `list` rather than the element you want so you need to use the `extract_first()` method or `extract()[0]`

eg

```
item['protein_name'] = site.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract_first()
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer

Answer (score -1):

Your xpath is wrong

- you don't need **`tbody`** to acess table rows
- simply use **`table/tr`** to access table rows

correct xpath would be :

```
sites = sel.xpath('//*[@id="middle_content_template"]//table//tr')
```

better xpath would be

```
sites = response.xpath('//table[@class="search_results"]/tr')
```

> as you can seen in above example, you do not need to create selector object
>   by `Selector(response)` to select xpath
>
> in newer scrapy releases, selector attribute is already added in response class  and one can use it with as mentioned below
>
> `response.selector.xpath(...)` or
>
> Short form `response.xpath(...)`

[Scrapy Selector](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector)