# Scrapy can't get data when following links

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have asked a question like this [Scrapy can't get data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497383/scrapy-doesnt-crawl-the-page). But I have a new problem when using another spider. I've pay attention to the xpath, but it seems like there is an same error in this program.

Here is my spider's code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy import Item, Field
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from DB_Connection import DB_Con

class UniParc(Item):
    database = Field()
    identifier = Field()
    version = Field()
    organism = Field()
    first_seen = Field()
    last_seen = Field()
    active = Field()
    source = Field()

class UniParcSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "UniParc"
    allowed_domains = ["uniprot.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.uniprot.org/uniparc/?query=rna&offset=25&sort=score&columns=id%2corganisms%2ckb%2cfirst-seen%2clast-seen%2clength"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//*[@id="results"]/tr/td[2]/a',)), callback="parse_items", follow = True),
    )

    def parse_items(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        sites = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="results"]/tr')
        db = DB_Con()
        collection = db.getcollection(self.term)
        for site in sites:
            item = UniParc()
            item["database"] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath("td[1]/text()").extract())
            item["identifier"] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath("td[2]/a/text()").extract())
            item["version"] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath("td[3]/text()").extract())
            item["organism"] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath("td[4]/a/text()").extract())
            item["first_seen"] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath("td[5]/text()").extract())
            item["last_seen"] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath("td[6]/text()").extract())
            item["active"] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath("td[7]/text()").extract())
            item['source'] = self.name
            collection.update({"identifier": item['identifier']}, dict(item), upsert=True)
            yield item
```

I used `rules` to extract the link which I want to follow and get data from it. But it seems like no urls have been got from the start_url.

Here is the log:

```
2016-05-28 22:28:54 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-05-28 22:28:54 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-05-28 22:28:54 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-05-28 22:28:54 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-05-28 22:28:55 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.uniprot.org/uniparc/?query=rna&offset=25&sort=score&columns=id%2corganisms%2ckb%2cfirst-seen%2clast-seen%2clength> (referer: None)
2016-05-28 22:28:55 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-05-28 22:28:55 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 314,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 12263,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 28, 14, 28, 55, 638618),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 28, 14, 28, 54, 645490)}
```

So can anybody tell what's wrong with my code? Is there something wrong with my xpath? But I've check this so many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix the following the links step, just fix the XPath expression, replace:

```
//*[@id="results"]/tr/td[2]/a
```

with:

```
//*[@id="results"]//tr/td[2]/a
```

And, as a side note, you should not be inserting the extracted items into the database directly in the spider. For that, Scrapy offers the [pipelines](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html). In case of MongoDB, check out [`scrapy-mongodb`](https://github.com/sebdah/scrapy-mongodb). Also see:

- [Web Scraping With Scrapy and MongoDB](https://realpython.com/blog/python/web-scraping-with-scrapy-and-mongodb/)

Comment: ok, with`//` I can get all the `tr` tags under `*[@id="results"]`, but if I use `/`, what can I get? Only one link?

Comment: And the mark `//` means overlook other tags, so do `//*[@id="results"]//tr/td[2]/a` and `//tr/td[2]/a` have the same effect?

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit with / you get nothing and, hence, no links are followed, that was the theory when I've looked into it. Thanks.